# How to split AWS CloudTrail JSON in FluentD

Tags: arrays, json, fluentd, amazon-cloudtrail

I have the following JSON and I need to split the array called Records into different messages in FluentD. I want to do that because all the elements inside that array are being ingested into the same document in ES and I can see only the first element in Kibana.

"The JSON is one single hash with the key “Records” pointing to a hash with the single key “message” containing an array where each element represents one API event. FluentD was now receiving these files, but only reporting one event from each file."

Things I've tried with no success:

- fluent-plugin-split_record
- fluent-plugin-jq
- fluent-plugin-split-array
- fluent-plugin-split
- [parsing-amazon-cloudtrail-jsoon-with-a-customized-logstash-build](https://techblog.mdsol.com/2014/01/27/parsing-amazon-cloudtrail-json-logs-with-a-customized-logstash-build.html) Reading similar issues with different tools

Anyone has any idea how to solve the problem?

```
{
  "_index": "abcd",
  "_type": "abcd",
  "_id": "abcd",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "Records": [
      {
        "eventVersion": "1.05",
        "userIdentity": {
          "type": "abcd",
          "principalId": "abcd",
          "accountId": "1234"
        },
        "eventTime": "2020-11-11T09:18:34Z",
        "eventSource": "abcd",
        "eventName": "abcd",
        "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
        "sourceIPAddress": "x.x.x.x",
        "userAgent": "abcd",
        "requestParameters": {
          "roleArn": "abcd",
          "roleSessionName": "abcd",
          "externalId": "1234"
        },
        "responseElements": {
          "credentials": {
            "accessKeyId": "",
            "expiration": "Nov 11, 2020 10:18:34 AM",
            "sessionToken": ""
          },
          "assumedRoleUser": {
            "assumedRoleId": "abcd",
            "arn": "abcd"
          }
        },
        "requestID": "0f34e4e7-0869-44ec-8185-189aa074ff23",
        "eventID": "d205f07f-1f30-4ba1-b99f-3fb929cdb9b7",
        "resources": [
          {
            "accountId": "123",
            "type": "abcd",
            "ARN": "abcd"
          }
        ],
        "eventType": "AwsApiCall",
        "recipientAccountId": "1234",
        "sharedEventID": "d10ccd8d-0489-4e56-9453-e3e3b00915d3"
      },
      {
        "eventVersion": "1.05",
        "userIdentity": {
          "type": "abcd",
          "principalId": "abcd",
          "arn": "abcd",
          "accountId": "1234",
          "accessKeyId": "",
          "sessionContext": {
            "sessionIssuer": {
              "type": "abcd",
              "principalId": "",
              "arn": "abcd",
              "userName": "abcd"
            },
            "webIdFederationData": {},
            "attributes": {
              "mfaAuthenticated": "false",
              "creationDate": "2020-11-11T08:35:54Z"
            }
          }
        },
        "eventTime": "2020-11-11T09:18:17Z",
        "eventSource": "abcd",
        "eventName": "abcd",
        "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
        "sourceIPAddress": "x.x.x.x",
        "userAgent": "abcd",
        "errorCode": "abcd",
        "errorMessage": "abcd",
        "requestParameters": null,
        "responseElements": null,
        "requestID": "cf92658d-c91b-cac4-97b7-cb14cd3db39a",
        "eventID": "dacac287-f47b-4299-94dd-d4b05b47325b",
        "eventType": "abcd",
        "recipientAccountId": "123"
      }
    ],
    "@timestamp": "2020-11-11T09:29:46.023523479+00:00",
    "@log_name": "cloudtrail.logs"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      "2020-11-11T09:29:46.023Z"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1234
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have the same question the answer is the following plugin [fluent-plugin-record_splitter](https://github.com/ixixi/fluent-plugin-record_splitter)

Example:

```
<match raw.cloudtrail.logs*>
  @type record_splitter
  tag cloudtrail.logs
  split_key Records 
</match>
```